Looking for an "animated hero" widget or tech on a WP site
I am looking for a way to create the following functionality -- whether via a plugin or something for Elementor (which I use as an amateur).
I'd like the Hero section to be a static image, but several images (separate hands grasping a soft drink bottle, which is my business) to pop up from the bottom, or the sides, in order to create something interactive and fresh, but without the overhead of video.
Any quick and dirty approaches to achieve this? I'd be willing to pay for a plugin if needed, but obviously prefer free ones :).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
